# Small data perfect, Large data wrong: A strange bubble sort question

Tags: c

I'm writing a bubble sort program.
I use TCC (http://bellard.org/tcc/)。
I use long long variables in my program, because the input data is very large.
My problem is : When the number of input data is small (e.g.10) my program works perfectly. But when the number of input data is large (e.g 5814) my program works wrong.

=========================================

My code and input data file is here: 
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=bfe8af46e42e3ecf&sc=documents&uc=4&id=BFE8AF46E42E3ECF!935

=========================================

Here is my program and testing data:

```
/*bubble.c*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    long long t,
        a[6001];    /*Change this to a[10000], then it works perfectly*/

    freopen("data.in.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("date.out.txt","w",stdout);
    scanf("%d",&n);

    /*Read input data from "data.in.txt"*/
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
        /*printf("i=%d\ta[i]=%lld\n",i,a[i]);*/
    }

    /*Bubble Sort*/
    for (i=1;i<=n-1;i=i+1) {
        for (j=n;j>=i+1;j=j-1) {
            if (a[j]<a[j-1]) {
                t=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j-1];
                a[j-1]=t;
            }
        }
    }

    /*Output data to "data.out.txt"*/
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
      printf("i=%d\ta[i]=%lld\n",i,a[i]);
    }


    /*printf("Time used =%lf\n",(double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);*/
    /*system("pause");*/
    return 0;
}
```

=================================

My input data: Very large numbers.

5814

209442427 
1519418927 828028199 47874386 1918308053 665370647 355436872 122922452 1361311685 1711685536 1850886562 752723777 567058321 1879534287 579940183 1802179021 2004892116 1219034394 269237342 410745567 849113437 ......

Comment: Arrays in C go from `0` to `n - 1`. Your way of writing the loops and whatnot is **very unstandard and difficult to follow**.

Comment: `scanf()` returns a value to indicate how many conversions it applied. Use that value. If it is not the expected value, you have an error in data.

Comment: Please post real source code that compiles, a is not declared

Comment: @CharlesB: it is, in fact (really unreadable though): the previous line ends with a `,`...

Comment: Just a thought, but why don't you create the array after you know how big it will be? Instead of making it too big for your needs, read in the number and set the array size to that.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded your files and compiled it with GCC 4.1.2 and with TCC 0.9.24 and you program works fine with both compilers.  The output matches right.date.out.txt, so your code is correct.  Perhaps there's something else in your environment that is causing problems compiling or running your program.