# Small data perfect, Large data wrong: A strange bubble sort question

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small data perfect, Large data wrong: A strange bubble sort question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706310/small-data-perfect-large-data-wrong-a-strange-bubble-sort-question)

My Code and input data file is here:
https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=bfe8af46e42e3ecf&sc=documents&id=BFE8AF46E42E3ECF!440#cid=BFE8AF46E42E3ECF&id=BFE8AF46E42E3ECF!935&sc=documents

I'm writing a bubble sort program.
I use TCC (http://bellard.org/tcc/)。
I use long long variables in my program, because the input data is very large.
My problem is : When the number of input data is small (e.g.10) my program works perfectly. But when the number of input data is large (e.g 5814) my program works wrong.

Here is my program and testing data:

```
/*bubble.c*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    long long t,
        a[6001];    /*Change this to a[10000], then it works perfectly*/

    freopen("data.in.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("date.out.txt","w",stdout);
    scanf("%d",&n);

    /*Read input data from "data.in.txt"*/
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
        /*printf("i=%d\ta[i]=%lld\n",i,a[i]);*/
    }

    /*Bubble Sort*/
    for (i=1;i<=n-1;i=i+1) {
        for (j=n;j>=i+1;j=j-1) {
            if (a[j]<a[j-1]) {
                t=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j-1];
                a[j-1]=t;
            }
        }
    }

    /*Output data to "data.out.txt"*/
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
      printf("i=%d\ta[i]=%lld\n",i,a[i]);
    }


    /*printf("Time used =%lf\n",(double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);*/
    /*system("pause");*/
    return 0;
}
```

=================================

My input data: Very large numbers.

5814

209442427 
1519418927 828028199 47874386 1918308053 665370647 355436872 122922452 1361311685 1711685536 1850886562 752723777 567058321 1879534287 579940183 1802179021 2004892116 1219034394 269237342 410745567 849113437 ......

Comment: What precisely does "wrong" cover?

Comment: Just a thought, but why don't you create the array after you know how big it will be? Instead of making it too big for your needs, read in the number and set the array size to that.

Comment: the last for condition also should be `i <= n-1`. You don't need to do `freopen` `stdin` and `stdout`, you could simple open other `FILE *` streams and use `fprintf` and `fscanf`

Comment: @Mat: "exact copy" would be a better wording :-)

Comment: The largest number in your list of "very large numbers", assuming it is representative of your entire dataset, uses less than 32 bits.  That will fit into an unsigned int on a 32 bit computer.  Using the long long type is overkill in the extreme.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using

```
scanf("%lld",&n);
```

when `n` is declared as `int`? This probably overwrites memory.